# Plot an oscillating function with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am plotting functions that oscillate fast as they approach 0. The oscillation seemed not recognized, and I got a simplified version of the function instead. How can I at least make some oscillations appear?

Here is a working example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
      declare function={
        func(\x)= (\x<-1) * (0) + 
        and(\x>= -1, \x<= 0) * ((\x-1)/2)   +
         and(\x>0, \x<=0.5) * (\x-0.5*sin(pi/\x))     +
         and(\x>0.5,  \x<=1) * (\x) +
         (\x>1) * (0);
      }
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
      axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
      ymin=-1, ymax=1, ytick={-1,0,1}, ylabel=$y$,
      xmin=-1, xmax=1, xtick={-1,0,1}, xlabel=$x$,
    ]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-1, 0, 0.5, 1}{
      \draw[dashed] ({rel axis cs: 0,0} -| {axis cs: #1, 0}) -- ({rel axis cs: 0,1} -| {axis cs: #1, 0});}
    \addplot[blue, domain=-1:1]{func(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is the displayed figure:
[image: incorrectfigure]

Comment: `samples=500,` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did try that, but the oscillation did not look effective as well: it does not look super different from the figure above, just with a tiny bit of oscillation close to the axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are straining tex arithmetic you might be better to use gnuplot or some other numerical system to generate the data and just use pgfplots to draw the final plot, but if I use the fp lib to get better arithmetic and increase the number of samples, I can just about get two oscillations

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
      declare function={
        func(\x)= (\x<-1) * (0) + 
        and(\x>= -1, \x<= 0) * ((\x-1)/2)   +
         and(\x>0, \x<=0.5) * (\x-0.5*sin(pi/\x))     +
         and(\x>0.5,  \x<=1) * (\x) +
         (\x>1) * (0);
      }
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
      axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle,
samples=1600,
      ymin=-1, ymax=1, ytick={-1,0,1}, ylabel=$y$,
      xmin=-1, xmax=1, xtick={-1,0,1}, xlabel=$x$,
    ]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-1, 0, 0.5, 1}{
      \draw[dashed] ({rel axis cs: 0,0} -| {axis cs: #1, 0}) -- ({rel axis cs: 0,1} -| {axis cs: #1, 0});}
    \addplot[blue, domain=-1:1]{func(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```